# What is the cause of this white scaling on my cactus?

Tags: houseplants, cactus

[image]

I’m not sure what type of cactus this is, but I’ve had it about a year and since getting it I’ve moved it into a pot with drainage. I’m careful with watering and do so about every 45 days as that’s what the previous owner had done. When I received it it did not have these spots. What could be happening, and is there anything I can do? Thanks!